# Exception attempting to deserialize Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization

I'm trying to serialize / deserialize some Xaml using this simple code:

```
object clone;
using ( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
{
  System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save( myStackPanel, stream );
  stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
  clone = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load( stream );
}
```

The actual Xaml is good because it has already been rendered to the UI.  When I attempt to deserialize a perfectly valid StackPanel, it throws a XamlParseException:

*"Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' threw an exception."*

The inner exception message is:

*"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Field'  Key being added: 'Field'"*

When I examine the serialized Xaml, there is no duplicate resource; there is a single Style element with x:Key="Field".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an instance of a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777480/xamlreader-load-throws-error-item-has-already-been-added-key-in-dictionary-newbrushkey-key-being-added-newbrushkey).

I suspect that what's happening is that XamlReader.Load is trying to add the key to the already-existing ResourceDictionary you must be defining in myStackPanel.  It's possible that you could have a work-around that didn't have the resources defined by Key or, for instance, put the resources in some higher-up resource dictionary.